# Why SD.exists() only looks for inside media/realroot on Intel's Galileo?

Tags: sd-card, arduino-galileo

I'm following a tutorial which says SD.exists() only look for files inside media/realroot on Intel's Galileo board. I just confirmed this using SSH to create e remove files during a loop which was looking for some specific named file. Where's information about this? I searched for cpp files inside SD library and found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Intel Galileo runs Linux.  Most Linux distributions (auto) mounts media under specific directories like "/media".  So this is likely not so much a feature of the Arduino paradigm but of the Linux paradigm.  If you really want to change this you will probably have to research how Linux (specifically how the Intel Galileo version of Linux) auto mounts media.

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214646/how-to-configure-the-default-automount-location) is a stack exchange question about auto-mounting using a Linux distribution called Ubuntu.  I am not sure how close the Intel Galileo Linux is to Ubuntu.  But it's a starting point.